# Create taxonomy terms from custom field values

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy, terms

I have a CPT 'Candidates', where its custom fields are being fetch from an API.

I am planning to convert/associate the values of these custom fields as taxonomy terms. Because I need to filter the 'Candidates' by these values. I was able to collect the values of these custom fields and place it in an array. Additionally, I managed to set the array of values as my dropdown filter. I guess I can query the 'Candidates' by tax query. However, I don't have any idea how I can associate the custom field values as taxonomy terms and select/create it automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: Since you're obtaining it via API you'd have to, rather than recording the values as custom fields, record them as custom taxonomy items.  Have you created a custom taxonomy yet?  You should really include code if you want better help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.